# sending email successfully with imap/pop disabled

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, imap

i have written a code to send email from a java desktop application to various email ids.
i noticed that the emails werent received with imap/pop disabled in my gmail account.

is this the case with all email providers?

and is there any way around this? because my app will be sending mails to unknown users and hence there can be no guarantee of imap being enabled in their inboxes.

also how do websites send automated emails? cause i can receive them all right without having imap/pop enabled.

i am using the javax.mail api to send these emails.

thanks

Comment: Why would imap/pop on the account have anything to do with delivery to the actual mailbox?

Comment: @Joe when i was trying it on some of my trial accounts on gmail, i was unable to receive any of the mails my app sent until i went into settings and enabled imap. Only then did i receive the mails

Answer (score -1):

In order to use gmail, use the following settings:
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.mail.Session"
              mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
              mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
              mail.smtp.port="465"
              mail.smtp.auth="true"
              mail.smtp.user=[user]
              password=[password]
              mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
              mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"

To make a website running in the tomcat servlet container send mail make sure your configure it as described in [javamail and tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions)